# restricting a view to a single category in xpages

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I have a view in xpages (AllCustomers) when I click on a link in this view it opens document editable(Customer form). There is a view in this page that display all project that relate to the selected Customer also there is a button called "Add existing projects in this page". This button should allow users to select a project that is created previously to this Customer. They should only be able to see the projects which are for the same customer and service as that of customer and add them to the customer. 
I created a view the first column of this view is categorized with Customer+services in column value, How can I filter a view panel to display projects that is created previously to the selected Customer.

Thanks a lot in advance

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel2" pageName="/Job.xsp">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager2">
                        </xp:pager>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="view2"
                            viewName="Dialogue">
                            <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getColumnValues("$16")}]]></xp:this.categoryFilter>
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$16" id="viewColumn11" style="width:75.0px">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader11">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$0" id="viewColumn12">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Num." id="viewColumnHeader12">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Progress" id="viewColumn13">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="%" id="viewColumnHeader13">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Estimate" id="viewColumn14">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Est." id="viewColumnHeader14">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Actual" id="viewColumn15" displayAs="link">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Act." id="viewColumnHeader15">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="status" id="viewColumn16">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Status" id="viewColumnHeader16">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Developer" id="viewColumn17">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Developer" id="viewColumnHeader17">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Priority" id="viewColumn18">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Priority" id="viewColumnHeader18">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Type" id="viewColumn19">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Typ" id="viewColumnHeader19">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="$11" id="viewColumn20">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Request" id="viewColumnHeader20">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                </xp:viewPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a view panel by setting the property "categoryFilter". If the first column of the underlying is categorized to the customer name, you can compute the categoryFilter to the current username. Now you can only see documents which have got the current username as customer in the first column.

```
 <xp:this.data>
     <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="luTimes"
                categoryFilter="#{javascript:session.createName(session.getEffectiveUserName()).getCanonical();}">
     </xp:dominoView>
 </xp:this.data>
```

Comment: I want to display projects that is created previously for the selected customer not the username.

Comment: You can also bind the category filter to a component value or a scope variable which contain the name of the customer

Comment: I tested with <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getColumnValues("$16")}]]></xp:this.categoryFilter>.....$16 is name of column that is categorized and Customer+Service is its value but it doesn't work

Comment: Please post your code of the view panel you are using